# sqlldr sql loader oracle inserir nome arquivo numa coluna

Tags: oracle

Será que consigo colocar o nome do arquivo que estou carregando numa coluna via sql loader?

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND INTO TABLE PFD_FILE
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
FILENAME char,
FILENAME_CERTIFICATION ,
DATE_CREATE "TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"
)
```